# The surface area of a sphere

Tags: integration, circles

My idea was like this. There is a circle which is represented by the equation $x^2 + y^2 = R^2 $, or if rearranged for $x > 0, \ y > 0$, $y = \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$.

$$A = 2 \int_0^R 2 \pi y \ dx = 4\pi \int_0^R \sqrt{R^2 - x^2} \ dx$$

But if I solve that I obtain ${\pi}^2 R^2$, which is not $4 \pi R^2$.

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you show your working out for getting $\pi^2R^2$ so we can try and work out where you have gone wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct formula for the surface area of the revolution which is  $$A = 2 \int_0^R 2 \pi y \ ds $$ where $$ds = \sqrt {1+(dy/{dx})^2} dx$$

With $$y=\sqrt {R^2-x^2}$$ you find $$ds = \frac {R}{\sqrt {R^2-x^2}}dx $$

You will find the correct answer with $$A = 2 \int_0^R 2 \pi y \ ds=2\int_0^R 2\pi R dx = 4\pi R^2$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I am convinced. But I am not clear about why the variable with which we are integrating should be $ds$, not $dx$?

Comment: @curious  it is $ds$  because the circle is curved and in order to account for the curve you consider $ds$ which is the element of the arc length instead of $dx$ which is flat.

Answer (score 0):

The equation for the sphere is

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$$

then it is convevient use [**spherical coordinates**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)

- $x=R\sin \phi \cos \theta$
- $y=R\sin \phi \sin \theta$
- $z=R\cos \phi $

and the set up for the surface area becomes

$$S=\int_0^\pi \:d\phi \int_0^{2\pi}R^2\sin \phi \:d\theta$$